# Change button image in web.py

Tags: web.py

I have the following code in my python script. How do I change the image of my button instead of the default ugly looking button?

```python
import web
from web import form

render = web.template.render('templates/')

urls = ('/','index')

register_form = form.Form(
    form.Textbox("name",size=40, description="Please enter name: "),
    form.Button("Query", type="submit", description="Query")
)
```

I was hoping to have an effect similar to this:

```html
< button>< img src="index.png">< /img>< /button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html option allows you to enter any html tags. :)

```
form.Button("Query", type="submit", description="Query" html="<img src="hello.png"/)
```